# NGINX server not proxying to server

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I am tring to proxy a test project that is served using the npm http-server module like so:

`http-server -p 8081`.

I have the following nginx configurations.

**nginx.conf**

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  4;

events {
    worker_connections  7684;
}  


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**sites-enabled/default**

```
upstream mysite {

    server 127.0.0.1:8081;

}

server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://mysite;
}
```

When I hit `localhost` it works.  When I hit `localhost:8081` it works.  However, when I enter `http://mysite` the console is giving me an ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error.  When I enter `mysite`, it just googles.  Can anybody explain what is going on and why it isn't being proxied appropriately?

Comment: If you have more questions just ask ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `server.listen 80` you create a local server on port 80. All requests (`location /`) are redirected (`proxy_pass`) to `mysite`. `mysite` is on localhost on port `8081`.

So you have to run another server on port 8081. And when you call `localhost:80` you are calling that on 8081.

EDIT: `mysite` is just an alias for nginx for an internal collection of backends (`upstream`). You can not call http://mysite from your browser. Instead just call http://localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You have two servers

- localhost:8081
- localhost:80

mysite - it just name of balancing method nginx.